# Current directory for C# ActiveX object loaded from HTML

Tags: c#, html, activex

I have an ActiveX object that I made with C# and registered in the system. I'm loading it with JavaScript in HTML like this:

```
<object id="myComComponent" name="myComComponent" classid="clsid:MY_ACTIVEX_GUID"></object>
```

This works fine. Now I want to open a file that exist in the same directory as the html inside the ActiveX object. The trouble is that I need the full path of the file and when I try

```
String curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

I get the path to my desktop, which is not where the file are. When I hardcode the file and path in the ActiveX object it works fine. What I want though is to be able to just give the file name (without path of course) as a parameter inside the OBJECT tag.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the path to your assembly?

```
var assemblyDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<object id="myComComponent" name="myComComponent" classid="clsid:MY_ACTIVEX_GUID">
    <param name="FileName" value="test.pdf" />
</object>
```

Which would be bound to a `FileName` property on your ActiveX class.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. The problem is how do I get the full path of the file.